# MySQL join syntax unknown column

Tags: mysql

Why is sm.status_id and sm.user_id getting an unknown column error? I don't usually use the `JOIN` keyword for table joins.

```
...
FROM questions q, connections sm
JOIN users u ON q.user_id = u.id
JOIN users lu ON q.last_user = lu.id
JOIN (SELECT q2.id FROM questions q2 WHERE q2.status_id = sm.status_id LIMIT 2) x ON x.id = q.id
WHERE sm.user_id = 38
GROUP BY th.id
```

Comment: How do you intend to join `questions` and `connections` together? You've got mixed syntax right now.

Comment: @dash ON q2.status_id = sm.status_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues with your current query.

First, you are mixing `JOIN` syntax. You have both comma separated values and then joins with an `ON` condition.

Second, you are attempting to access an alias for a table in an inner subquery which you cannot do.

My suggestion is to try something like this:

```
FROM questions q
JOIN users u 
    ON q.user_id = u.id
JOIN users lu 
    ON q.last_user = lu.id
JOIN 
(
    SELECT q2.id 
    FROM questions q2 
    JOIN connections sm
        ON q2.status_id = sm.status_id 
    WHERE sm.user_id = 38
    LIMIT 2
) x ON x.id = q.id
GROUP BY th.id
```

You did not post your `SELECT` list but if you want to include fields from the `connections` table in the `select` list then you will need to join on it again or include the fields in the subquery.

Comment: thanks, problem with this is that it only gets 2 questions in total, I want 2 questions for each status that exists :( I think what I'm trying to do isn't possible with just one query so I'll just have to abandon elegance :(

Comment: Can you edit your OP and post the table structures, sample data and then the desired result?  Or create a sql fiddle with the data.  That would be helpful is getting you the correct answer. :)

Comment: Don't you can have an upvote, I'll just have to use some PHP to format it

Comment: @amiawizard sure, whatever you prefer.  I have no problem trying to help you solve it through SQL though.

Comment: Somehow I need to get every row from connections sm so obviously I can't use limit 2 as the query currently does..

Comment: If you remove the `LIMIT 2` do you get the results that you want?  If you want to limit by group here are some examples of how to do it -- http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: That gives too many results, millions of rows from the question table for each status, I could just format this result set with some PHP but it could get problemlatic for server load..

Answer (score 0):

The reason is :: You need to use that columns in your select clause to make it visible inside the subquery like :

```
Select status_id ,sm.user_id
FROM questions q, connections sm
JOIN users u ON q.user_id = u.id
JOIN users lu ON q.last_user = lu.id
JOIN (SELECT q2.id FROM questions q2 WHERE q2.status_id = sm.status_id LIMIT 2) x ON x.id = q.id
WHERE sm.user_id = 38
GROUP BY th.id
```

Comment: Show us the create construct of connections and table q2